# how duplicate proof is to create a firebase document with the generated uuid v4?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, uuid

I am working on an app the will inject docs in to firestore database those docs will have an id generated by uuid v4 the question is could 2 user every user on a different browser created same doc with the same id ? since the uuid function is the same ? if a duplicated could occur it will overwrite someone's data! in case if uuid is generation the ids not by timestamp.
other wise 2 users will have same reference which also really bad case ! could npm uuid be used for this purpose ?

```js
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
const id = uuidv4();
```

Comment: Any reason you can't simply use Firebase's built-in `add()` method?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can I access  the created id ? in context api before is it getting created ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I need access to the id because it serves 2 purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the ID of a document you're adding to Firestore before the document is actually added, have a look at this section of the Firebase documentation on [adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document):

> In some cases, it can be useful to create a document reference with an auto-generated ID, then use the reference later. For this use case, you can call `doc()`:
>
> ```
> import { collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
>
> // Add a new document with a generated id
> const newCityRef = doc(collection(db, "cities"));
>
> // later...
> await setDoc(newCityRef, data);
> ```

This is the JavaScript code for v9 or later of the SDK. Code for other languages can be found at the link above.